# Image processing configuration

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I need help with image processing configuration in Typo3 7.6.4. All images are being processed no matter how big they are. That causes that the images are not in original size and unsharp, renamed and copied in *processed* folder. I would like to configure image processing so that it is activated only if images have some specific size (px or kb/mb). For example if image have more than 1MB or if the is width more than 800px, than processed it otherwise leave it as it is and link to original file (no copy, no processing). Thanks

```
    page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
    template = CASE
    template {
      key.data = levelfield:-1,backend_layout_next_level,slide
      key.override.field = backend_layout

      1 = FILE
      1.file = fileadmin/templates/sitename/main_1_column.html

      2 = FILE
      2.file = fileadmin/templates/sitename/main_2_column.html
    }
    partialRootPath = fileadmin/templates/sitename/partials/
    layoutRootPath = fileadmin/templates/sitename/layouts/
    variables {

      siteName = TEXT
      siteName.value = sitename

      header < styles.content.get
      header.select.where = colPos = 0

      contentMain < styles.content.get
      contentMain.select.where = colPos = 1

      content_column_1 < styles.content.get
      content_column_1.select.where = colPos = 1

      content_column_2 < styles.content.get
      content_column_2.select.where = colPos = 2

      footer < styles.content.get
      footer.select.where = colPos = 3
  }
}

tt_content {
    stdWrap {
        innerWrap {
            cObject {
                default.20.40 = CASE
                default.20.40 {
                    key.field = layout

                    default = TEXT
                    default.value = img-responsive
                }
            }
        }

        innerWrap2 >
    }

    image {
        20 {
            1 {
                params.cObject = TEXT
                params.cObject {
                    wrap = class="|"
                    cObject < tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default.20.40
                }
                sourceCollection >
                sourceCollection {
                    big {
                        maxW = 5000
                        dataKey = big
                    }
                    small {
                        maxW = 500
                        dataKey = small
                    }
                    smallLandscape {
                        maxW = 800
                        dataKey = smallLandscape
                    }
                }
            }
            maxW = 5000
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While the file size limitation makes no sense at all images are by default not upscaled using fluid image viewhelper. That being said you can use the original unprocessed images by using the originalResource from a file reference.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a typo3 rookie. Can you post a sample or point me to some source?

Comment: What is the context here? Are we inside a fluid template?

Comment: Yes, we are inside Fluid Template.

Comment: Ok, please add the code from your fluid template to the original question and I'll fix it in an answer.